# Should I upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 kernel

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, upgrade

I am currently running the 3.5.0.48 kernel on my Ubuntu 12.04.4, and I was wondering whether I should upgrade to 3.8 or 3.11.

[This](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/07/upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-lts-kernel-to-3-4/) makes it seem easy enough. Though I will wait with throwing away my current kernel for now.

Can someone list reasons not to upgrade? And potentially other / better ways to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running the Saucy kernel on both my development machine and my in-house server without problems. I followed the [official Ubuntu guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) for LTSE enabled stacks.

As with any change, your primary question should be: for what do I need this. If there is no need, and you are not just investigating things for fun, why run the risk of breaking your setup.

The main reason for me to do so (I mean upgrading, **not** breaking) was that I have btrfs filesystems that had performance problems.

Comment: +1 for don't fix it if it isn't broken.

Comment: I am considering it because my Intel wireless network card has issues which I have not been able to fix, and I was *hoping* that it would miraculously be solved by upgrading.

Comment: @Oxidator This is a good reason. Have you look through the kernel changelogs to see if there is something new for your card in last kernels?

Comment: @Oxidator AFAIK the change is reversible, i.e. deinstalling 'saucy' packages will leave you with your system as it were. Trying to get something that is not working (properly) to work is a good reason, but for a wireless network card you might just need a new driver.

Comment: @Igeorget I haven't, couldn't really find something either. (Not sure where to look). @ Anthon I couldn't use the official guide, because of dependency issues. I installed 3.11 successfully the other way, but that increased the wifi issues. So I'm reverting back I guess.